# Run Word 2013 from command line

Tags: command-line, ms-word, ms-office, office-2013, word-2013

Some of our clients have a problem we can not reproduce here inhouse: Out software uses MS-Word for producing form letter. Since some of our clients use Office 2013, this function won't work anymore.
We tried to reproduce this and detect that on the affected systems Word won't start from command line. Starting via the link in the startmenu works. It also works to start Excel from command line.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the solution:
Our software still uses old 8.3 filenames - also long filenames are replaced with short ones. And it seems that Office 2013 don't like them anymore.

Answer (score 13):

You can try using start.exe from the command line:

```
c:> start winword
```

I'm wasn't familiar with it but tried it and it worked for me on Windows 7, with Office 2007.  Found [this](http://www.windows-commandline.com/run-command-for-word/) site (windows-commandline.com).  They claim it works for all versions of Word.

Comment: Adding link to Microsoft Office Support article, which contains documentation for all of the parameters for `start winword`:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6

Answer (score 3):

Just an FYI similar to Word
for Excel on command line and parameters

```
c:\> start excel "file path and location"

c:\> start excel "c:\somepath\myfile.xlsx"
```

worked for us to open a file created in VB 6.0 for Excel 2013

```
c:\excel does not work on command line for us either
```

I think WinWord will work with a file parameter too.

```
c:\> start winword "c:\somepath\myfile.doc"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the executable location and file in Office 2013, as listed in the shortcut.  You cannot start it by using `winword` either, in Win 8 32 bit.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\winword.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the run prompt by pressing the windowsbutton+R. The run prompt will open and then Type **winword** to open MS Word and **excel** to open MS Excel.